# issue with replicating anaconda environment in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, anaconda, conda

I have an anaconda enviroment in my ubuntu laptop.
This is part of the yml:

```
name: root
dependencies:
- _license=1.1=py27_0
- abstract-rendering=0.5.1=np19py27_0
- alabaster=0.7.3=py27_0
- anaconda=2.3.0=np19py27_0
```

I edited this yml file and sent it to the ubuntu server. Below is part of the edited file:

```
name: test2
dependencies:
- _license=1.1=py27_0
- abstract-rendering=0.5.1=np19py27_0
- alabaster=0.7.3=py27_0
- anaconda=2.3.0=np19py27_0
```

But when I execute `conda env create -f environment.yml` i get the below error

```
Solving package specifications: Error: 'conda' can only be installed into the root environment
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work with a recent `conda`. Deactivate your environment if you have one activated:

```
source deactivate
```

Update `conda`:

```
 conda update conda
```

Try your installation again.

Comment: i downloaded a new anaconda. its a very new version which was downloaded 1 week back.

Comment: Works for me with `conda 3.19.0`. Check with `conda --version`.